# List of commands defined in CTAN packages

Tags: macros, packages, ctan

Are there any resources available that list the control sequences/commands available from each package on CTAN (or other TeX hosting sites)?

I understand they are shown in the documentation PDF's, but this is rather tedious to look through and generate a list.

As an aside, why is this not required when submitting a package? Seems like it would be very helpful to package writers if they knew what commands are defined and where.

Comment: there are thousands of packages on ctan, and some of them define thousands of commands, what would you do with such a list that you couldn't do with a google search of ctan?

Comment: For package writing, you should always use an internal namespace unique to your package or class for package internal commands (e.g. `\mypkg@foo` etc.) to avoid name clashes.  For user facing commands, if you have a name that's the same as another package's name, the chances are that the packages shouldn't be used together anyway.  So it's not clear what a list would do for you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Heck, I don't even remember all the commands defined in my *own* packages!

Comment: The list might be useless in some sense that some commands are just overwritten by packages or changed or improved or screwed up...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Pretty easy for your packages: `\StackUp`, `\StackDown`, `\StackBelow`, `\StackBehind`, `\StackAfter`, `\StackBefore`, `\StackHere`, and thousand variants :-P

Comment: @AlanMunn I don't see how this would not be helpful for package writers. If I am writing a package to be used in conjunction with package X, and maybe package Y, Z, ..., I surely want to make sure we aren't multiply defining commands.

Comment: User-facing macros are typically named in ways that describe their functionality, so either you're writing a package with competing functionality (in which case name overlaps are likely not an issue) or you're writing a package which is not competing, in which case names are less likely to overlap. And if you know your package will be used in conjunction with another package, presumably you will check its macro names from its own documentation. But the number of such overlaps should generally be small. Macro name clashes do occur, but rarely, and often from poorly named internal macros.

Comment: @AlanMunn fair enough. I understand, I just think it would be good practice. Imagine I write a package, and define a macro, I could easily see if that macro name exists on CTAN and what package it is defined in. I don't think it is fair to assume everyone is knowledgable about every package.

Comment: @AlanMunn Moreover, the OP should be using `\newcommand` etc. wherever possible for user-facing stuff. So just loading the draft package after the others will throw up errors if there's a clash.

Comment: The fact is, people are already reluctant to upload their packages to CTAN. Another requirement would just be a further hurdle. Consequently, bug fixes, updates and new stuff would be even more likely to languish in the obscurity of GitHub.

Comment: the basic TeX Primitive Control Sequences that form the foundation https://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html

Comment: @nate It is not that useful to know if a package defines a macro. Take `indentfirst` the full text of that is `\let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue\@afterindenttrue` so at a technical level it defines no user-usable commands, but a more useful definition is that it affects every sectioning command such as `\section` to make it indent the following paragraph, conversely almost every math font package has to define _all_ the math commands such as `\alpha` or `\rightarrow` etc and say which font they are in in the  new setup,  but listing every math command for every font package isn't useful.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the sceptical tenor of the comments above - I don't see how such a list would be useful in real life. However, just for the heck of it, here is a little bash script that *attempts* to list all commands in all locally installed `*.sty` files.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# search file system for all latex package files
packages=$(sh -c "find / -name '*.sty' | grep -oE '/([^/]+)/[^/]+\.sty$' | cut -f2 -d'/' | sort | uniq" 2>/dev/null)

# iterate over all packages to list their macros.
for package in $packages; do
    # run Martin Scharrer's `latexdef` on each package name to list the
    # commands defined therein. The loop hangs on arsclassica, so we 
    # skip it.
    if [ $package != "arsclassica" ]; then
        echo "package: $package"
        latexdef -l -p $package
    fi
done
```

Note that `latexdef` invokes TeX on each package, and sometimes that doesn't work properly, and you get compile error messages. You also get some empty lines, so you would have to filter the output. Also, it seems the compiler hangs when `latexdef` tries to process package `arsclassica`, which I therefore manually excluded. Since I only ever let the script run to package names starting with letter `c`, it is quite possible that more hangups would occur, and more exemptions be required, further on.

Also note that this does not cover `*.cls` or other files that may contain command definitions.

Comment: +1 for the `-l` option of `texdef` alone. And if you want internal macros too, you can use `-ll`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Do you actually *have* `latexdef`? If so, where from? `texdef -t latex` is what I usually use, but the help *promises* `latexdef`. I just don't have it.

Comment: @cfr Just make `latexdef` a symbolic link to `texdef.pl` in `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Why `/usr/local/bin/`? For persistence?

Comment: @cfr Probably. I don't really remember. Mine has been on my system there since 2013. I may have installed it manually at some point, since checking the link it resolves to a version in `/usr/local/bin`.  I've never understood why the link isn't automatically included in TL.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks. It certainly works. They provide a link for `texdef`. Seems odd not to do the same for `latexdef` if they link the same thing. (I assumed `latexdef` was some kind of wrapper for `texdef` which I didn't have.)